# how do I do dual redirection on one line in bash?

Tags: bash, redirect

I'd like to run du, and redirect the stdout to one file, and stderr to another file.

I have the line:

```
    du -ah / | sort -h >/home/username/stdout.txt 2>/home/username/stderr.txt
```

I know this should always produce errors because things in /proc/ aren't as tangible as du would like them to be - that's fine.  This line will populate stdout.txt with everything I want to see, but stderr still spills out into the console, and the stderr.txt file remains empty.  Is there a way to do staggered redirections like this or will I have to run the line twice, each line with its own redirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're capturing the error stream issued by `sort`, not by `du` (which has no redirection on stderr) which explains that your file is empty.

You want to sort the output of stdout, and capture the errors of the `du` command in stderr (unsorted). Do it for instance like this:

```
du -ah / 2>/home/username/stderr.txt | sort -h >/home/username/stdout.txt
```